# Unable to connect Express to Oracle DB

Tags: node.js, oracle, express, node-oracledb

I am trying to build a rest api using Express js with Oracle db but i am unable to connect the DB

I have created index.js as below

```
const oracledb = require("oracledb");

oracledb.outFormat = oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT;

var connectionProperties = {
  user: process.env.DBAAS_USER_NAME || "hr",
  password: process.env.DBAAS_USER_PASSWORD || "hr",
  connectString: process.env.DBAAS_DEFAULT_CONNECT_DESCRIPTOR || "localhost/xe",
};

async function run() {
  oracledb.getConnection(connectionProperties, function (err, connection) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      //   response.status(500).send("Error connecting to DB");
      return;
    }
    console.log("After connection");

    console.log(result.rows);
    connection.close();
  });
}

run();
```

DB version :

SQL> SELECT BANNER from v$version;

### BANNER

Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.2.0      Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

Package.json as below

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "oracledb": "^6.0.2"
  }
}
```

Getting the error as

```
NJS-138: connections to this database server version are not supported by node-oracledb in Thin mode
```

Tried different ways but no luck . Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76429178/why-am-i-getting-the-njs-138-connections-to-this-database-server-version-are-n. Add a call to `initOracleClient()` to enable [Thick mode](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#enabling-node-oracledb-thick-mode) which does connect to your old DB version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting the "NJS-138: connections to this database server version are not supported by node-oracledb in Thin mode" error with node-oracledb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76429178/why-am-i-getting-the-njs-138-connections-to-this-database-server-version-are-n)